# Почему может не писаться текст в Textarea?

Tags: html, вёрстка, javascript

На странице создается динамически текстовое поле Textarea:

```
<textarea class="EditComment">Pri</textarea>
```

С такими стилями:

```
.EditComment {
width: 890px;
height: 80px;
font-size: 12px;
background: url(../images/best_answer_a.png) repeat-x;
}
```

Из поля можно удалять текст - но дописывать нельзя почему-то. Что может быть причиной?

Comment: Покажите код, лучше на jsfiddle. Видимых причин нет, могу предположить только какой нибудь preventDefault() на keypress(down, up) и то врятли.

Comment: Вы оказались правы с keypress(down, up) return fasle;
Большое спасибо